# Why is my python output delayed to the end of the program?

Tags: python, delay, stdout

I've got an extremely simple application:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

for i in range(3):
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sleep(1)

print('Welcome!')
```

I expect it to print out a dot every second (3 times), after which it should display "Welcome!". Unfortunately, it simply waits three seconds, and then prints out everything at once. I'm on a mac running regular Python 2.7 and I have no clue why this code behaves like this. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python output buffering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering) for further details (and more advanced ways to do what you want).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because `sys.stdout` is buffered. Use `flush`:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

for i in range(3):
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(1)

print('Welcome!')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can call python with `-u` to make stdin, stdout, and stderr totally unbuffered. This would save you from having to manually flush them.

On Unix, call your script like `python -u myscript.py`

Or you can put it in the shebang: `#!/usr/bin/python -u`

Answer (score 1):

`stdout` is a buffered stream. The buffer is flushed implicitly when it reaches a newline character.

If you want to flush the buffer without writing a newline character, you must do so explicitly by calling `sys.stdout.flush()`

Another alternative is to write to `stderr`, which is not buffered.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `print` or a `logger`.

If you want the behaviour you expect, you need to to use `sys.flush` to force the output.