# Docker logs latency with custom Python image

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, mqtt

I have a Python script I run from a Docker container and I have it print out what it's doing so that I can view that in `docker logs -f <container>`.  The logs do print...but they seem to print in "batches" as opposed to real-time.  They used to show up in real-time and I don't know what has changed.

The relevant part of the script:

```
point = f"temp value={temp}"
topic = f"lp/things/{client_name}/temp"
print(f"Publishing to topic: {topic}\n\tPayload: {point}")
(rc, mid) = client.publish(topic, point, 2, retain=True)
time.sleep(2)
```

I've confirmed that it is publishing on the 2-second schedule it's supposed to by looking at the broker it's publishing to.

Here is the Dockerfile that creates the image I run:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
ADD requirements.txt /
ADD mqtt_client.py /
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["/mqtt_client.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/python3"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610870/why-is-my-python-output-delayed-to-the-end-of-the-program/17610891

Comment: @GambitSupport does it matter that I'm using `print` as opposed to `sys.write()`?  Also, this isn't an issue outside of Docker.  When I run it directly on the host, it prints at the expected cadence.  Is this just a Docker quirk?

Comment: stdout buffering is non-deterministic. Google is your friend. It gives me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574702/how-to-print-to-stderr-in-python